# Create a function to handle errors -python

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm designing a code that recreates the same logic as a flowchart. I've made a function that allows you to interact with the questions and it works fine, until you input something other than 'yes' or 'no'. I want to create a function that, for every input answer, if it is different than yes and no, it should say to input it again, and then keep going from where it left off.

So I tried

```
    def error(x):
    while True:
        if x.lower() != "yes" or x.lower() != "no":
            tryagain = input("Please only enter 'yes' or 'no'\n")
            return (error(tryagain))
        continue
```

But after asking me to input the answer again, even if I type yes or no, it just keeps on repeating "Please only enter 'yes' or 'no'". I've also tried other codes (for loops, ifs and elifs, while loops worded differently) but they don't work. I'm currently working without packages, as I'm still learning the basics.

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: The replies to that question either use packages or try/except, but I do not get an error message if I don't enter yes or no, the program stops working or keeps on asking me the same question

Comment: Try `and` instead of `or`? Alternatively, `if x.lower() not in ["yes", "no"]:`

Comment: The accepted answer is broad and covers a wide range of use cases; yours is under *"Implementing Your Own Validation Rules"*.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a continue statement at the wrong place. When the questions are answered with yes or no your program should continue to next step. However when user enters anything else it should prompt to enter input with 'yes' or 'no'

You can try this

```
   def error(x):
       while True:
           if (x.lower() == "yes" or x.lower() == "no"):
              break
           else:
              tryagain = input("Please only enter 'yes' or 'no'\n")
              return (error(tryagain))
```

It should work.

Comment: When I input yes or no it just doesn't return anything else

Comment: yes, that is because we are writing continue in case the user inputs 'yes' or 'no'. you should use break instead if you want to go back to the previous code where you are calling error(x) function.

Comment: Edited my answer as per your requirement.